# How to type long strings without having to scroll horizontally in android Resource file

Tags: android, string, resources

I am trying to store long text messages as String Resources in Android. But I have to scroll the editor horizontally if I type the whole string in a single line. But when I try to type in multiple lines, then the line breaks reflect the same when I try to read the string.

I want to type the string in multiple lines in the Android resource XML file (So that I don't have to scroll horizontally to read the entire text). But when I read it, I do not want the line breaks from the XML file. I want to read the string as a single line.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can set soft wrap on Android Studio "View -> Active Editor -> Soft-Wrap"